# Firebase Crashlytics upload missing dysm files

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics, swift-package-manager

I have firebase integration with swift package manager. I followed the official guide

`https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/README.md`

With in-build settings enable bit code is set to yes. Debug info format is set DWARF with dYSM file.
I have a run script that is supposed to upload the dSYM file to crashlytics
`${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/firebase-ios-sdk/Crashlytics/run`
I have another run script that adds the GoogleService-info.plist file to the project root.

```
   "Debug (Development)" | "Release (Development)" )
        cp -r "$PROJECT_DIR/{project-name}/Firebase/GoogleService-Info-dev.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

   "Debug (QA)" | "Release (QA)" )
        cp -r "$PROJECT_DIR/{project-name}/Firebase/GoogleService-Info-qa.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;


   "Release (Production)" | "Debug (Production)" )
        cp -r "$PROJECT_DIR/{project-name}/Firebase/GoogleService-Info-prod.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist" ;;

    *)
        ;;
esac
```

I am not able to see the crash reports consistently. I have a few of them coming up and the rest of the times I see Upload missing dSYM required to process crashes. I know firebase has some wait time but I have waited long enough to know I am missing a few crash reports.

When debugging with Xcode I did follow the standard procedure of detaching the debugger and then running the app to force a crash and then running back on the simulator.

I also tried running from an actual physical device by installing an IPA and I still can't see the all crash reports.

With Xcode and firebase debug enabled I can see [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Completed report submission with id:{some id here}, but still can't see the report on the dashboard.

What am I doing wrong here? Why is crashlytics not getting my crash reports.

Comment: For the missing dSYMs, are you sure they were uploaded to the correct project?

Comment: did you solve your issue?